# Can't see "Tag Image" stage in Deck UI

Tags: spinnaker

Are there any requirements for the pipeline so that [Tag Image stage](https://www.spinnaker.io/reference/pipeline/stages/#tag-image) is visible on the UI?

A scenario I want to achieve using a Spinnaker pipeline is:

1. trigger pipeline on a docker image update;
2. test it as Run Job;
3. in case of tests passing tag the image with some addition label.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to add "Tag Image" stage. Deck simply does not show it.

I run Spinnaker 1.10.12.

Answer (score 1):

According to source code image tagger available only for Google/Amazon registries.

See realted classes:

[ImageTagger](https://github.com/spinnaker/orca/blob/master/orca-clouddriver/src/main/groovy/com/netflix/spinnaker/orca/clouddriver/tasks/image/ImageTagger.java)

[GoogleImageTagger](https://github.com/spinnaker/orca/blob/master/orca-clouddriver/src/main/groovy/com/netflix/spinnaker/orca/clouddriver/tasks/providers/gce/GoogleImageTagger.java)

[AmazonImageTagger](https://github.com/spinnaker/orca/blob/master/orca-clouddriver/src/main/groovy/com/netflix/spinnaker/orca/clouddriver/tasks/providers/aws/AmazonImageTagger.java)